# How to declare several CANVAS with different contexts (ctx) in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas

I'm using several CANVAS in a HTML file and I want to declare them in an Array. This is the (not array) declaration:

```
var canvas0 = document.getElementById('canvas0');
var ctxPaint0 = canvas0.getContext('2d');
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctxPaint1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctxPaint2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
var ctxPaint3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
```

To optimize this, I'm trying to use *For* loops, but it doesn't work:

```
var canvasArray = ["canvas0","canvas1","canvas2","canvas3"]; 
for (var i = 0; i < canvasArray.length; i++) { 

window["canvas"+i] = document.getElementById(canvasArray[i]);
window["ctxPaint"+i] = canvasArray[i].getContext('2d');

}
```

It outputs this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: canvasArray[i].getContext is not a function
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to RSchneyer, changing the Array of strings to an Array of Canvas works fine now:

```
let canvasArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"));
for (var i = 0; i < canvasArray.length; i++) { 

window["canvas"+i] = document.getElementById(canvasArray[i]);
window["ctxPaint"+i] = canvasArray[i].getContext('2d');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like

```
const ctxArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="canvas"]')].map(cvs => cvs.getContext('2d'));
```

which will result to an array holding all the canvases context - which is all you need, since to get the original canvas out of its context all you need is i.e.:

```
let i = 0; // or any desired index
const canvas = ctxArray[i].canvas;
```

Comment: @mrbang those Are contextes. If you know how to loop an array you can retrieve any context by the desired index

Comment: Yes, I see it now, I never worked with map before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`canvasArray` is an array of strings, which don't have a `getContext()` function. Try replacing the `canvasArray[i]` in `window["ctxPaint"+i] = canvasArray[i].getContext('2d');` with `window["canvas"+i]`, or create another array to hold your actual canvas variables